# plot path of points

Tags: qgis, r, tools

I have a sample of the address histories of households.

```
ID  ZIP1   ZIP2   ZIP3
01  XXXXX  XXXXX  XXXXX
02  XXXXX  XXXXX  XXXXX
03  XXXXX  XXXXX  XXXXX
04  XXXXX  XXXXX  XXXXX
...
```

It's easy enough for me to find the centroids of the ZIP codes. What I would like to do is link those centroids together to create an image showing household `i`'s path from `ZIP1` to `ZIP2` to `ZIP3`.

Does anyone know any tools to make this easy in QGIS (or even better: R)? I have the feeling there must be some tool, but I don't know enough to think of what the name would be.

Comment: So basically you want to create polygons from points?

Comment: Well, the object would be a polyline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should try to get geographical information for your zip-codes (geocode them). Without any real points you can't construct a polyline so therefore you should start with that.
With the help of R you can easily geocode a lot of addresses using web-services. See a [little example here on my blog](http://conservationecology.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/return-coordinates-of-address-in-r/). Of course you might have to change the code to your needs and possibly also consult other geocoding services.
The resulting data.frame can be converted to a spatial-object (package **sp** - `coordinates(data) = ~x+y`) and then be saved to a shapefile (package **rgdal** - `writeOGR(...)` ).

As soon as you have your point layer grouped with a ID you can import it into QGIS and use the excellent plugins Points2One or Points to Path.

Comment: I figured a much easier way to get the spatial information would be by linking the ZIP code information to ZCTA TIGER files, which I already have. And my points are already geocoded anyways. The problem is that each point has multiple pairs of coordinates, and I need a way to map the links. Will look at Points to Path.

Comment: The `Points to Paths` package worked for me.